# XSD restriction: is it possible to define a pattern based on an enumeration?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I'd like to restrict a field so that it can only begins with some specific values.
This is what I tried:

```
<xs:simpleType>
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="(green apple)+|(blue orange)+|(lemon 123)+"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

and also

```
<xs:simpleType>
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="(green apple|blue orange|lemon 123)+"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Doing so, I was hopping that
green apple: valid
green apple (Gala): valid
red apple: not valid

But none of these attempts were successful. Any idea how I could achieve that?

EDIT: I changed so enum values, so that they now contain whitespace

Comment: Downvoting. Changing a question in such a way as to invalidate existing answers is just thoroughly confusing for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You want

```
<xs:pattern value="(apple|orange|lemon).+"/>
```

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't validate: Value 'green apple' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '(green apple|blue orange|lemon 123).+'

Comment: Well, if you change the question, then of course the answer will have to change too.

Comment: Sorry, i realised that the white space could change the situation so I updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Define each phrase as their own pattern.

```
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:pattern value="green apple.*" />
              <xs:pattern value="blue orange.*" />
              <xs:pattern value="lemon 123.*" />
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: Thanks. To complete it, in order to validate "green apple", I add to use  <xs:pattern value="green apple.*" />